# How To List Members of a Role Assignment Using Azure SDK for .Net Core?

Tags: .net-core, azure-sdk-.net

I've been studying the Azure SDK for .NET Core documentation but there doesn't seem to be a class that I can use to list the members of a Role Assignment. I will be using the list of members to authorize users to my app. Can anyone maybe point me to the right direction?

Comment: Could you please tell me what you mean Role Assignment? Is that you want to list Azure rabc role assignment https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-list-portal?

Comment: @JimXu Yes, something like that, but I would like to do it programmatically.

Comment: Have you referred to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-list-rest?